# How to send email with flutter where the recipient is known but the sender changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've read how both mailer and flutter_email_sender work.
But I don't think they solve my problem.
I need to be able to always send emails to the same address, for example emailsample@gmail.com
But change the sender, because each user who will use my app will have a different email.
I couldn't find anything that could help me online.
So is there a way to send an email with a different sender, without asking for the email password?
They are emails for example of non-functioning of a certain function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package [url-launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
  onPressed: () => setState(() {
     _launched = _createMail(
     'mailto:emailsample@gmail.com?subject=subject of email');
     },
   ),
 label: Text('E-Mail')),
```

add this to your widget:

```
  Future<void> _createMail(String url) async {
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```